# How to access certain div class after it is created

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I select that shop-container class after it is created and add innerHTML to it.
Right now it gives me an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null.

What I want to do is make this code work when it finds certain type of product to be automatically added to its segment (e.g. shirt type contains only shirts in its segment)

```
const shop = document.querySelector(".shop");
const shopContainer = document.querySelector(".shop-container");

class Shop {
  constructor() {
    this.getItems();
  }
  async getItems() {
    let result = await fetch("../products.json");
    let data = await result.json();
    View.renderItems(data);
  }
}

class View {
  static renderItems(result) {
    result.forEach(item => {
      View.oneItem(item);
    });
  }
  static typeContainer(type) {
    if (shop.innerHTML.indexOf(`${type}`) === -1) {
      let temp = `         
            <div class="${type}">
              <h1>${type}</h1>
              <div class="shop-container">

              </div>
            </div>
        `;
      shop.innerHTML += temp;
      console.log("succ");
    }
  }
  static oneItem(item) {
    let temp = `<article class="shop-item">
          <div class="item-img">
            <img src="img/shop/${item.id}.png" alt="" />
          </div>
          <div class="item-info">
            <h1>${item.name}</h1>
            <h3>${item.style}</h3>
            <hr />
            <div class="item-cart">
              <h3>${item.price}<small>rsd</small></h3>
              <button class="order-btn" data-id="${item.id}"><i class="fas fa-cart-plus fa-2x"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </article>`;
    View.typeContainer(item.type);
    shopContainer.innerHTML += temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you rendering DOM with a class?

Comment: [`document.querySelector(".className");`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: @ScottMarcus I know that, that is exactly the problem, it returns null.

Comment: If you are using that code AFTER the element has been created, it won't be as long as the className is correct.